# What are the user data returned from Person or Group column (People Only) query?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, spservices, caml, query

I'm using `SPServices` to query a SharePoint Online (2013) list that contains a `Person` or `Group` column. (This column is set to allow selection of People Only, in case that matters.)

The query used is below.

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='ComponentID'></FieldRef>
            <Value Type='Number'>151</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
    <QueryOptions><ExpandUserField>TRUE</ExpandUserField></QueryOptions>
</Query>

<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='RequiredApprovers' />
    // some other fields of other types
</ViewFields>
```

The response I get is below.

`[userID = 6];#Skip Baker,[account = #i:0#.f|membership|sbaker@example.com],#sbaker@example.com,#sbaker@example.com,#Skip Baker,#[Photo URL],#[Department Name],#[Job Title]`

I want to parse the string into a User data object, which I know how to do. However, I don't know what all of the parts of the string are, and I don't want to rely on something being an email address when it's really a domain user name, etc. I've used brackets to indicate the parts I believe I understand. Can anyone tell me what the other parts of this string are?

Comment: Can you update the SPServices query you are using? It depends on what all information you are requesting.

Comment: Happily - one sec :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.expanduserfield(v=office.14).aspx

Whether to use special rendering for user field values that makes them include the login name, e-mail address, Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) address, and title, when present, which causes a user field to behave as a multilookup field.

**You don't need to manually parse data**

```
function userToJsonObject(s) {
    if (s.length === 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        var thisUser = s.split(";#"); 
        var thisUserExpanded = thisUser[1].split(",#")
        if(thisUserExpanded.length == 1) {
            return {userId: thisUser[0], userName: thisUser[1]}
        } else {
            return {
                userId: thisUser[0], 
                userName: thisUserExpanded[0].replace( /(,,)/g, ","), 
                loginName: thisUserExpanded[1].replace( /(,,)/g, ","), 
                email: thisUserExpanded[2].replace( /(,,)/g, ","), 
                sipAddress: thisUserExpanded[3].replace( /(,,)/g, ","), 
                title: thisUserExpanded[4].replace( /(,,)/g, ",")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://spservices.codeplex.com/workitem/10071

Comment: That function doesn't actually return all the parts of the string I provided, so manual parsing is still required. However, I was able to find the unknown property names I was looking for inside the function. Thanks :)